# Missing subfigure when used with overpic

Tags: subfloats, overpic

I am trying to use subfigure with overpic but the pictures are missing. I followed the tutorial here https://shantoroy.com/latex/add-subfig-in-latex/

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.8\columnwidth,trim={0 2cm 0 0},clip]{figures/experiments/p1_1_0000004168.png}
\end{overpic}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{overpic}width=0.8\columnwidth,trim={0 2cm 0 0},clip]{figures/experiments/p1_1_0000004168.png}
\end{overpic}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{test}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure*}
```

But I get the image here. How do I get latex to show it ?

[image]

Comment: The `subfigure` environment need a mandatory argument setting the width (as a minipage)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the mandatory argument in subfigure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{overpic}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \begin{overpic}[width=0.8\columnwidth,trim={0 2cm 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
            \end{overpic}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \begin{overpic}[width=0.8\columnwidth,trim={0 2cm 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}
            \end{overpic}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{test}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```